# How to Combine Wifi and Ethernet for increased bandwidth?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, network-traffic

I have 2 mobile phones with seperate data connections and I can connect one of them to my laptop through a USB tethering mode and the other as a hotspot connection.

For example the individual connection caps at about 500 Kb/s of speed and if I'm downloading a file from Chrome I wont be able to watch a youtube video.
So what I'm looking for is, I use connection 1 for the chrome download and connection 2 for Youtube streaming.
I wanted to know if there is a way I can connect both of them simultaneously to my laptop such that I can utilize them together.
Maybe something like a free software/method that would specifically redirect the connections for a software over the specified networks.

Comment: @Ramhound It depends if the phones are using their data, or wi-fi. If data, you should theoretically be able to.

Comment: @mbomb007 - I have only see that done with additional hardware (load balancer) and the bandwidth wouldn't necessarily be doubled.

Comment: I agree with ramhound here. Sure dual wan routers, and load balancers you can access both simultaneously. Technically there would be more bandwidth available **if you divided all the ports/protocols evenly over both connections** but for a single service like http or https, there will be no gain over what a single connection can deliver for a single host.